# Push notification is not popping up react-native-firebase with starter kit

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

I have cloned [React Native Firebase Starter](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase-starter) and did initial setup then renamed project according to the docs then added `google.services.json` file (what was generated with app name `com.xxxxx.xxxx`).

Then i tried running in android device.

Screen i am getting that messaging service is enabled but when i do create new message from cloud messaging tab of firebase. I am not getting any notification in device.

I am using real device and checked with multiple devices. also notification settings are allowed.

Please help me out thanks in advance.